# Can heaps really only use O(1) auxiliary storage?

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, heap, binary-search-tree, space-complexity

One of the biggest advantages of using heaps for priority queues (as opposed to, say, red-black trees) seems to be space-efficiency: unlike balanced BSTs, heaps only require O(1) auxiliary storage.
i.e, the ordering of the elements alone is sufficient to satisfy the invariants and guarantees of a heap, and no child/parent pointers are necessary.

However, my question is: is the above *really* true?

It seems to me that, in order to use an array-based heap while satisfying the O(log n) running time guarantee, the array *must be dynamically expandable*.

The *only* way we can dynamically expand an array in O(1) time is to **over-allocate** the memory that backs the array, so that we can amortize the memory operations into the future.

But then, doesn't that overallocation imply a heap *also* requires auxiliary storage?

If the above is true, that seems to imply heaps have no complexity advantages over balanced BSTs whatsoever, so then, what makes heaps "interesting" from a theoretical point of view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to confuse binary heaps, heaps in general, and implementations of binary heaps that use an array instead of an explicit tree structure.

A binary heap is simply a binary tree with properties that make it theoretically interesting beyond memory use. They can be built in linear time, whereas building a BST necessarily takes n log n time. For example, this can be used to select the k smallest/largest values of a sequence in better-than-n log n time.

Implementing a binary heap as an array yields an implicit data structure. This is a topic formalized by theorists, but not actively pursued by most of them. But in any case, the classification is justified: To dynamically expand this structure one indeed needs to over-allocate, but not every data structure has to grow dynamically, so the case of a statically-sized pre-allocated data structure is interesting as well.

Furthermore, there is a difference between space needed for faster growth and space needed because each element is larger than it has to be. The first can be avoided by not growing, and also reduced to arbitrarily small constant factor of the total size, at the cost of a greater constant factor on running time. The latter kind of space overhead is usually unavoidable and can't be reduced much (the pointers in a tree are at least log n bits, period).

Finally, there are many *heaps* other than *binary heaps* (fibonacci, binominal, leftist, pairing, ...), and almost all except binary heaps offer better bounds for at least some operations. The most common ones are *decrease-key* (alter the value of a key already in the structure in a certain way) and *merge* (combined two heaps into one). The complexity of these operations are important for the analysis of several algorithms using priority queues, and hence the motivation for a lot of research into heaps.

**In practice** the memory use *is* important. But (with over-allocation and without), the difference is only a constant factor overall, so theorists are not terribly interested in binary heaps. They'd rather get better complexity for decrease-key and merge; most of them are happy if the data structure takes O(n) space. The extremely high memory density, ease of implementation and cache friendliness are far more interesting for practitioners, and it's them who sing the praise of binary heaps far and wide.

Comment: +1 amazing answer, thanks! Question though: decrease-key can be implemented just as easily on a binary heap as other heaps, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad Depends on what you mean by "easy". The problem isn't getting decrease-key right, the problem is making it fast (without making other operations slower). For binary heaps, no known algorithm is better than removing the old key and inserting a new one, taking linear time. Most other heaps are constructed such that a more efficient (sub-linear) decrease-key is possible and *reasonably* simple. It's hard to compare ease of implementation here, in particular because it depends on the heap variant in question (they greatly vary, and it also depends on how much you want to optimize).

Comment: Wait, really? I'm confused because if you look at [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/heap/d_ary_heap.html#id750023-bb) they have absolutely no trouble implementing decrease-key and increase-key for a d-ary heap (so d = 2 here) in logarithmic time... am I missing something?

Comment: @Mehrdad That method requires a handle on the node that has changed. Theorists include the time to find that node, i.e. decrease-key is supplied a key value and has to find the position inside the heap. That's justified because if you can't do it fast using only your heap, you need a second data structure to find the handle fast, or need to do linear search (this is assumed in the O(n) bound for binary heaps). If you do have a handle, go nuts. But if not, and you use a more sophisticated heap structure, you can do better than logarithmic time with zero extra effort or memory.

Comment: Oh! So you really mean "find-element" is logarithmic time for other heaps, not the "decreasing" part... wow I didn't realize that. But in that case, if you can find *any* element in logarithmic time, doesn't that mean you necessarily have a BST in front of you? At least, isn't that exactly what a BST-based "set" data structure does -- let you check for existence of elements in logarithmic time?

Comment: @Mehrdad Note that you can't necessarily *find* elements that quickly, only decrease them (you can always decrease it to be less than the current minimum and then pop-min, but pop-min is logarithmic in that case). Also, a BST is a very specific beast (a binary tree with strong restrictions on the elements in each subtree); most heaps aren't even binary trees let alone fulfill the restrictions on sub trees. How exactly these bounds are achieved, and what caveats prevent them from being general-purpose collection murderbeasts, depends on the heap in question.

Comment: That's bizarre... you can decrease something that you can't find? Guess I have a lot more reading to do, on the face of it it sounds like a logical impossibility. Thanks so much for the pointers! (no pun intended)

Comment: @Mehrdad Actually, let me revise that. After decreasing it, you can find it in O(1) time. You just can't remove it (which you can with a self-balancing BST). I still think decreasing is easier than finding for some structures (including some contrived ones), but I'd have to do some more research before giving an example.